# Best practice including Angular UI in Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, include, dependencies, angular-ui

I would like to use the following plugin in my grails application http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/. The download contains a bower.json to resolve the necessary dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
"angular": "~1.2.x",
"jquery": "~2.x",
"jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
"fullcalendar": "~1.x"},"devDependencies": {
"angular-mocks": "~1.x",
"bootstrap-css": "2.3.1"}
```

What would be the best practice to include this in a grails project, because i don't think that manually adding all these files by hand is the way to go.

Comment: you could use bower, as usual, from command line. not sure if there is a plugin for bower

Comment: I'd consider decoupling the architecture also and that way you aren't mixing two ecosystems. Let Grails be the backend services project and let Angular be the rich, front end client that consumes it.

Comment: Currently we have a grails API as backend . But we still need a little bit of grails for the actual application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Things I do

I am not sure if it is the best practice but as `@Igor Artamonov` mentioned I am managing my client code using bower (in `web-app` folder), for now it is a development time only procedure and after doing `bower install` actual necessary files are then referenced in `ApplicationRecources.groovy` and later on are minimized, obfuscated, etc using grails plugins.

The tradeoff is that files installed with `bower` contain a lot of unnecessary stuff and usually get exposed which is not what you would need. But using something like `spring security` you can block access to those files.

#### In node.js

In `node.js` project I would have `Grunt` tasks that prepare dev assets to production assets and put those somewhere and production version would not even have previously installed stuff.

#### Additional thoughts

So my guess is that I still need a `watched` directory that is never gonna be in production and after something changes there, necessary assets are copied to `web-app` folder after being optimized, obfuscated, etc. Maybe in addition to `bower` I should introduce `grunt` tasks as well, maybe there is a need for a new plugin, but that is for the future.